# windows phone save base64 to png (in an Cordova/Phonegap app)

Tags: cordova, png, base64, windows-phone

I'm writing an app that merges images on a canvas element and then saves it to disk. Got this working in iOS and android but I can't find anything on how I can convert a base64 string to png ( or jpg, bmp dont really care...) and save it to the file system.

I'm using cordova 1.7 and the windows phone 7.1 sdk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does the Base64 string contain?

Comment: it's a base64 encoded image. Basically I take the images draw them on canvas (for an overlay effect) and then convert it to base64 via the .toDataUrl method

Comment: did You solved the problem?